# Form sending mail despite validation errors

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have just built my first PHP contact form with validation and yet it is sending an email regardless. I must have missed something. Can anyone spot it?

```
<?php if($_SESSION['instance'] == '1') {

    $email = $_POST['ENQemail'];
    $firstname = $_POST['ENQfirst_name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['ENQlast_name'];
    $message = $_POST['ENQmessage'];
    $secword = $_POST['ENQsecword'];



  if (!ereg("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)) {
    $ERRemail = 'invalid email address';
  }
  if (strlen($firstname < 2)) {

    $ERRfirstname = 'Please enter your first name';
  }
  if (strlen($lastname < 2)) {

    $ERRlastname = 'Please enter your surname';
  }
  if (strlen($message < 50)) {

    $ERRmessage = 'Your message must be at least 50 characters';
  }
  if ($secword == $_SESSION['instance']) {

    $ERRsecword = 'Your security word did not match the image';
  }

  else {

      $to = "enquire@divethegap.com";
  $subject = "DTG Enquiry - ".$firstname." ".$lastname ;
  $message = $message;
  $headers = "From: ".$firstname." ".$lastname." ".$email. "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


  }
    }
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sidenote: Be aware that "^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$" will not validate every valid email address. E.g somebody has address with more than one @ sign (escaped in username part like \@), ipv4 or ipv6 address in domain part, escaped special characters, etc. You can't validate e-mail with one simple line because its form is very complicated. Check [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) for more info and follow RFC standards mentioned on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` statement that contains the email-sending code is only associated with the *previous* `if` statement.  This means that the only time it will *not* be called is if `$secword == $_SESSION['instance']` evaluates to `false`.  It doesn't matter whether the other validation checks succeed or not.

One strategy is to keep track of all the errors that occurred by storing them in an array.  If the array is empty, then you know all the fields are OK and that it is safe to send the email:

```
$errors = array();
if (!ereg("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)) {
  $errors[] = 'invalid email address';
}
if (strlen($firstname < 2)) {
  $errors[] = 'Please enter your first name';
}
//...

if (count($errors) == 0){
  //send the email
  mail(...);
} else {
  //display the error messages
}
```

Your code looks pretty good otherwise!  Here are some other suggestions:

- In order to use sessions in PHP, you
  must first call the `session_start()`
  function.  This should be the very first thing your PHP script does.
- The `ereg()` function
  has been deprecated in the latest version of PHP.  This means that the function may be removed in a future version of PHP.  It is recommended that you use the  `preg_match()` function instead (note that with
  `preg_match()`, the regex string must
  begin and end with a `/` character).

Answer (score 0):

You're doing all the validations independent of each other and you send out the email if the security image is correct irrespective of whether everything else passed the check or not because your `else` to send the email matches up with the `if ($secword == $_SESSION['instance']) {`

You could do one of the following:

1. Change all the `if`s but the first to `elseif`s so that only if *all* checks pass will the last `else` (which sends the email) be entered

   ```
   if (!ereg("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)) {
       $ERRemail = 'invalid email address';
   }
   elseif (strlen($firstname < 2)) {
       $ERRfirstname = 'Please enter your first name';
   }
   elseif (strlen($lastname < 2)) {
       $ERRlastname = 'Please enter your surname';
   }
   elseif (strlen($message < 50)) {
       $ERRmessage = 'Your message must be at least 50 characters';
   }
   elseif ($secword == $_SESSION['instance']) {
       $ERRsecword = 'Your security word did not match the image';
   }
   else {
     $to = "enquire@divethegap.com";
     $subject = "DTG Enquiry - ".$firstname." ".$lastname ;
     $message = $message;
     $headers = "From: ".$firstname." ".$lastname." ".$email. "\r\n" . "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   }
   ```
2. Set a flag indicating if any check failed. And at the end, only send the email if everything worked out:

   ```
   $isValid = true;

   if(invalidEmail){
       $isValid =false;
   }

   if(invalidName){
       $isValid =false;
   }

   //finally send mail if all validation passed
   if($isValid) {
      //send email
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom is a fixed version of the logic. You missed the "else if"s.

Also the following line looks like it should check for inequality but it depends on your code so you would know better:

```
if ($secword == $_SESSION['instance'])
```

Here is the full fix:

```
    <?php if($_SESSION['instance'] == '1') {

    $email = $_POST['ENQemail'];
    $firstname = $_POST['ENQfirst_name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['ENQlast_name'];
    $message = $_POST['ENQmessage'];
    $secword = $_POST['ENQsecword'];



  if (!ereg("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)) {
    $ERRemail = 'invalid email address';
  }
  else if (strlen($firstname < 2)) {

    $ERRfirstname = 'Please enter your first name';
  }
  else if (strlen($lastname < 2)) {

    $ERRlastname = 'Please enter your surname';
  }
  else if (strlen($message < 50)) {

    $ERRmessage = 'Your message must be at least 50 characters';
  }
  else if ($secword == $_SESSION['instance']) {

    $ERRsecword = 'Your security word did not match the image';
  }

  else {

      $to = "enquire@divethegap.com";
  $subject = "DTG Enquiry - ".$firstname." ".$lastname ;
  $message = $message;
  $headers = "From: ".$firstname." ".$lastname." ".$email. "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


  }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well if you else if then it will stop after it has checked the first field and not flag up the next fields

Comment: In that case you should use the approach I've described as option #2 in my answer above.

Comment: Hi Robin, If you want to show all the "errors" together then you need to use a flag variable just like no.good.at.coding suggests.